# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate more than one Backbone.RelationalModel with the same id per type

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-relational

I'm using Backbone Relational in a Backbone Marionette app. If I follow this workflow:
Navigate directly to the show page > click "Home" (or index page) link > click the browser's back button to go back to the show page I get an error which causes the page not to load:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate more than one Backbone.RelationalModel with the same id per type!
```

It seems the issue is that the model is already  in memory so Backbone Relational doesn't want to re-fetch it. It has a built in helper to help with this - [findOrCreate](http://backbonerelational.org/#RelationalModel-findOrCreate). I followed the backbonerails.com tutorials which has you setup a nifty "when:fetched" function that basically runs whatever code you want to run after the model has been fetched from the server.

I've been trying to adjust this to instead use the `findOrCreate` function but thus far have been unsuccessful. Any ideas how I should update this to use the `findOrCreate` call instead of the `fetch` call?

```
@TheoremReach.module "Utilities", (Utilities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  App.commands.setHandler "when:fetched", (entities, callback) ->
    xhrs = _.chain([entities]).flatten().pluck("_fetch").value()

    $.when(xhrs...).done ->
      callback()
```

Alternatively, is there a way to access the "model in memory" that already exists and is throwing this error? I've been searching but haven't been able to figure out where that's stored/how to access that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `findOrCreate` to instantiate the model and then fetch it.

```
var model = MyModel.findOrCreate({id : modelId});
model.fetch();
```

Comment: So apparently my problem was that I was trying to call findOrCreate on the model instance itself instead of the Class. This worked like a charm once I adjusted

Comment: Yeah, glad I could help. In general `BackboneRelational` can be a pretty weird library. Let me know if you run into any more gotchas.